# Resize a matrix in Java

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, interpolation, resampling

I have a matrix `double[][]` with arbitrary dimensions but bigger than 300 (maybe in one or maybe on both dimensions). I want to scale it to `double[300][300]`.

My main approach is to interpolate the matrix and bring it up to `double[600][600]` and then take four elements and find their average, i.e. the elements `0,0`, `0,1`, `1,0` and `1,1` will be the `0,0` of the final 300x300 matrix.

I have found the interpolation library in JAVA but I cannot figure out how to use it. Can anyone provide some examples or info?

The library is: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/java-media/jai/forDevelopers/jai-apidocs/javax/media/jai/Interpolation.html

Thnx.

Comment: Thank JB Nizet. You are correct and I'm sorry but I'm a bit dazed from all the searching. I just edited the question and I posted the library.

Comment: Do you have anyone code showing what you have attempted so far?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No Tim. This process that I want to achieve is a small part of a bigger one. So, I do not have any code that presents what I have done so far. Also, I do not ask any solution :) Just an example of how to use the Interpolation of Java.

Comment: Then write a small test program. If you have trouble with that, then you have some code to show in your question that will follow the Stack Overflow guidelines of *Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable*: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. We will then be happy to help.

Comment: @Andreas the problem is I do not know how to use the Interpolate class... So, writing a mcve is a problem by it self. This is the reason that I ask for help. If I could write even a small example, then by various methods I would have the answer my self.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for something like this, which I found by Googling the full class name: [Java Code Examples for 'javax.media.jai.Interpolation'](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=javax.media.jai.Interpolation)

Comment: @Andreas I have also found this. But if you had a better look instead of just c/p the web page/link, you would see that the interpolation class is used only as an argument to image handling methods. I do not need to handle images!

Comment: And also, in the provided link there is **NO** example of how to use the interpolation class by it self but only in conjunction with image handling classes (which also can be seen if someone has a look at the web page and not just provide the link)

Comment: @Kostas the Interpolation class about which you are looking example is meant for handling images. The javadoc says it's An object encapsulating a particular algorithm for image interpolation (resampling). So maybe you need to look for more general purpose matrix scaling algorithms: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=matrix+scaling+algorithm

Comment: @alainlompo Thnx! I will have a go... although that I think that already googled that... Anyway, If I do not find anything I will comment on the question. Thnx anyway alainlompo.

Comment: That's not helping. What I want to do it exactly what I wrote in the question. I want to interpolate a series of numbers with the Interpolation class. Is that possible in Java?

Comment: Regarding transforming from 600x600 to 300x300 you could use lineal transformations.

Comment: Yes... that part is solved before asking the above question. What I want to do is from NxM to 600x600, where N > 300 and/or M > 300

Answer (score 1):

What about writing a simple method that maps source cells to destination, then averages out?

```
public static boolean matrixReduce(double[][] dst, double[][] src) {
    double dstMaxX = dst.length - 1, dstMaxY = dst[0].length - 1;
    double srcMaxX = src.length - 1, srcMaxY = src[0].length - 1;
    int count[][] = new int[dst.length][dst[0].length];

    for (int x = 0; x < src.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < src[0].length; y++) {
            int xx = (int) Math.round((double) x * dstMaxX / srcMaxX);
            int yy = (int) Math.round((double) y * dstMaxY / srcMaxY);

            dst[xx][yy] += src[x][y];
            count[xx][yy]++;
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < dst.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < dst[0].length; y++) {
            dst[x][y] /= count[x][y];
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```